# how to use unwind in neo4jclient for updating data?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to update some of my records in the neo4j DB. In order that I wrote this query in Neo4jClient in C#:

```
 _client.Cypher
            .Unwind(skills, "updatedSkill")
            .Match("(s : Skill {Name: updatedSkill.Name}")
            .Set("s = updatedSkill");
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Where skills is a simple list of Skill objects:

```
    public class Skill
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Phrase { get; set; }          
        }
```

But this code throws exception when I call it. Its translated Cypher query is:

```
UNWIND [{
    "Name": "name1",
    "Phrase": "phrase1",
},{
    "Name": "name2",
    "Phrase": "phrase2",
}] AS updatedSkill
MATCH (s : Skill {Name: updatedSkill.Name}
SET s = updatedSkill
```

The exception is as follows:

```
     Invalid input '"': expected whitespace, comment, an identifier,
 UnsignedDecimalInteger, a property key name or '}' (line 3, column 5 (offset: 17))
    "    "Name": "name1","
         ^
```

When I remove the double-quotes of the properties Name and Phrase the query runs correctly. But I can do it because the query is auto-generated by Neo4jClient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `MATCH` statement. It is missing the closing `)`. If you correct this your query should work as expected. As an aside there is also an extra semi-colon at the end of your `SET` statement, which I have removed.

```
_client.Cypher
        .Unwind(skills, "updatedSkill")
        .Match("(s:Skill {Name: updatedSkill.Name})")
        .Set("s = updatedSkill")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

As an aside, this is an example where the query you are looking at it not truly representative of the parameterized query being sent to the Neo4j REST API. I assume that you obtained it by looking at `_cypher.Query.DebugQueryText`? For most situations this is just fine but where you are passing JSON objects it can lead to a misleading query due to the way it manipulates the string representations of the parameter objects. If you look at the actual exception being thrown by Neo4jClient it *should* inform you of the real cause of the issue. In this case

> SyntaxException: Invalid input 'S': expected whitespace, comment, ')' or a relationship pattern...
>   "SET s = updatedSkill"
>    ^

This tells you the real problem is that you have not closed off your `MATCH` statement before starting the `SET` statement.