# How to import Json using Neo4jClient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to serialize the Json and deserialize node into Json using Neo4jClient,Is there anyone can give me a exmple?

Thx Z.Tom

Comment: Perhaps you could let us know a little more detail on what you are trying to do?

Comment: It would be great if you could give some C# example code showing the flow you're trying to achieve, particularly the classes you're trying to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

looking to do the same myself and this link seems very helpful

[how to use unwind in neo4jclient for updating data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262667/how-to-use-unwind-in-neo4jclient-for-updating-data)

create var jsonPayload for your json string

then

```
Client.Cypher
.Unwind(jsonPayload, "PersonData")
.WithParam("jsonpayload", jsonPayload)
.Merge("(p:Person { uid: PersonData.uid })")
.Set("p += PersonData.atts")
.ExecuteWithoutResults()
;
```